# Error on scalar value as an array

Tags: php, arrays, scalar

Can some one help me with this code with a error on scalar value as an array?

```
$getal = $_POST['getal'];

For($teller=1; $teller<=11; $teller=$teller+1)
{
    $uitkomst[$teller]=$teller*$getal;
}
```

Comment: What is `$uitkomst` variable ?

Comment: And what is the exact error you are getting?

Comment: What does `var_dump($uitkomst);` output? It's probably a number. You need to use an array instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$getal = $_POST['getal'];
$uitkomst = array();
For($teller=1; $teller<=11; $teller=$teller+1)
{
  $uitkomst[$teller]=$teller*$getal;
}
```

Comment: Still curious about your error, since I could run your code (assuming $_POST['getal'] = 5) without error. PHP will deduce from this code that $uitkomst should be an array, although your code doesnt adhere to strict coding standards.

Comment: Maybe because I allready got a other $_post $getal code in my script?<?php
if(!empty($_POST['submit']))
{
 $getal=$_POST['getal'];
 for($teller=1; $teller<11; $teller=$teller+1)
 {
  $uitkomst = $teller * $getal;
  echo "$teller X $getal = $uitkomst <br>";
 }
 
 $getal = $_POST['getal'];
 $uitkomst = array();
  For($teller=1; $teller<=11; $teller=$teller+1)
  {
  $uitkomst[$teller]=$teller*$getal;
  }